# Validating boolean properties

Tags: c#, validation, properties, boolean

I feel abit embarrassed asking about this. Cant seem to find it described anywhere else though...

Say, we have a webservice method, StoreNewItem(Item item), that takes in a datacontract with all the properties for the item.
We will insert this new item in a database.
Some of the properties are mandatory, and some of these are boolean.

Should we validate the incomming data, i.e. verify that the mandatory fields actually have valid data, or should this be the responsibility of the client calling the webservice?

If yes, how to handle the boolean properties? The client may well ignore them, and they will be stored as false in db, as we have no way of knowing if they where set to false or just ignored/forgotten by the client.

Is it a valid option to use an enum with True, False and Empty instead of bool as a type for these mandatory properties?
Or is this simply not our problem?

All thoughts are welcome!

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Reasuring they where all so similar :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of enums, you can use nullable booleans (bool?) which are fully supported by web services.

IMHO Your checking logic should at least be in the db which can forward the error to the service layer (which in turns should raise a fault). I'd have it at the service level too though so that the error can be raised before hitting the db (validation is part of the business layer too). Having it in the UI too is nice but not mandatory.

Never assume your clients send you valid data.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely validate the data. Malicious entities could easily replicate your clients.

Answer (score 0):

it depends by your business rule.

you could use optional parameter if you want to allow the use not to pass some parameters but you want them got a default value

```
void MyServiceMethod(bool CanDoIt=false,int somethingElse)
```

or you can make your service get nullable value if you want allow the user not to pass all the  parameter using null value(if your business rule can allow that)

```
void MyServiceMethod(Nullable<bool> canDoItfalse,int somethingElse)
```

In general you should always validate the Data on the Service side and return a service fault data contract in the case the validation fails

more info at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752208.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If no external third party will be accessing the web service (used only in-house), you can get away with not validating in the service.  Personally, I wouldn't do that though; it's too easy to have bad data sent to the service.  Plus, then you would have to duplicate all the validation logic across all clients.  So validating in the service is a must in my opinion.

As far as booleans, you can use nullable booleans (`bool?`).